# Better phrase for "lengthy date"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Is there a better phrase or word to use than *lengthy date*? For example:

> We give this **lengthy date** to accommodate the dispute respecting the Hermas who is the author of the Pastor.

This seems a bit archaic to me. Is there a better word, phrase or anything else to express the above thought?

Note, [Hermas](http://classic.net.bible.org/dictionary.php?word=Hermas) was “a man in Rome to whom Paul sent greetings”, second century, possibly  “the author of the celebrated religious romance called *The Shepherd*” or *The Pastor*.

Comment: This sentence makes no sense to me after "dispute". Is the dispute about who is the author? Is *the Pastor* a story or a person?

Comment: @Rachel: jwpat7 put the reference to the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear without more context, but I presume *lengthy date* here means a date at a relatively far point in the future.

Instead of the given term you could use the following:

> We give this **distant future date** to accommodate the dispute respecting the Hermas who is the author of the Pastor.
>
> We give this **long lead time** to accommodate the dispute respecting the Hermas who is the author of the Pastor.
>
> We give this **much time in advance** to accommodate the dispute respecting the Hermas who is the author of the Pastor.

Answer (score 1):

Examining what I take to be your source, Peters' [*Theocratic Kingdom*](http://books.google.com/books?id=9ew2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA495&lpg=PA495&dq=%22We+give+this+lengthy+date%22&source=bl&ots=0KWeUfEO0T&sig=aD3uXZYu2czvgTbWMeTIXf3cTNw&sa=X&ei=7AY1ULn5OYS6rQHvqoDIAg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22We%20give%20this%20lengthy%20date%22&f=false), it appears that the author is explaining why he suggests an unusually long period of time, "from A.D. 40 to 150", as the timeframe within which the *Pastor of Hermas* might have been written.

It's an awkward construction. If I had been around in 1884 I might have written something like "We give this very long range of possible dates to accommodate differing opinions respecting the identity of Hermas the author of the *Pastor* with the Hermas mentioned in Rom. 16:14."

Comment: Assuming that this is the intended meaning, I second the thoughts here. I would say something like "we give this [long/extended/wide/broad] [period/range (of dates)]".

Answer (score 0):

In courts, lawyers will often ask for a ***long date*** or a ***short date***.  This refers to how quickly the next hearing/trial will occur.  Complex cases where bail has been granted usually try for a long date in order to adequately prepare a case.  Simple cases where bail has not been granted will ask for a short date, to get it over with quickly.

Comment: Can I say: after the interview they usually give you a short date to hire you, to mean that they don't delay the hiring after the interview? Or long date to mean otherwise?